# Module URI constructor explain

Tags: ruby, module, uri

```
require "uri"

u = URI.parse("https://www.google.com")  #<URI::HTTPS https://www.google.com>
v = URI("https://www.google.com")        #<URI::HTTPS https://www.google.com>
u == v                                   # => true
```

The `URI.parse` is easy to understand, it calls *module_function* `parse` on Module `URI`.

How to understand `URI()` in Ruby's context? What method does it called? Or is this a syntactic sugar?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What, *specifically* is it that you don't understand? How to call a method? How to define a method?

Comment: Not sure what `URI()` is. Turns out to be same as `Kernel#URI`. It's a module_function defined in `uri/common.rb`. I'm a little bit confused because we normally don't name method with Capital letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best answer on your question is source code. Code below executes when you call `URI('http..')`

```
def URI(uri)
  if uri.is_a?(URI::Generic)
    uri
  elsif uri = String.try_convert(uri)
    URI.parse(uri)
  else
    raise ArgumentError,
      "bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)"
  end
end
```

As you can see under the hood this method allows you to pass any argument and be sure that program will throw `ArgumentError` if argument wasn't uri or instance of uri. So, in my opinion good practice to use `URI('...')` than `URI.parse('...')` with additional checks.

Feel free to check it out by yourself: [github ruby repo mirror](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/uri/common.rb#L705)

Comment: Thanks for looking into. It's a little bit weird that the method name starts with Capital letter.